# Android: Change color of navigationView selected item programatically

Tags: android, navigationview

I created a drawer with a navigation view. In an other part of the activity, I have a button. When I click on this button, I want the selected item of the navigation view to change its color. 
Do you know how to do that?

Edit:
For now I tried this:

```
private void changeNavigationColor(int resColor){
    int[][] state = new int[][] {
            new int[] {android.R.attr.state_checked} // unchecked
    };
    int[] color = new int[] {
            getResources().getColor(resColor)
    };
    ColorStateList colorStateList= new ColorStateList(state, color);
    navigationView.setItemTextColor(colorStateList.getColorForState());
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(colorStateList);
}
```

But it is changing the whole colorListState whereas I just want to change it the check state

Comment: please include code what you have tried so far to achieve this

Comment: I have just edited my comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_dashboard"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_item"  // add this 
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawer_item" // add this
        app:menu="@menu/activity_dashboard_drawer" />
```

drawer_item.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="AFTER_CLICK_CHANGE_COLOR_TEXT" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="NAVIGATION_DRAWER_TEXT_COLOR" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Yes but in this xml code the color will change when I click on the item. Or I want the color of the current clicked item to change when I click on an other button in the activity

Comment: replace this NAVIGATION_DRAWER_TEXT_COLOR to #AEAEAE for default text color and then replace this AFTER_CLICK_CHANGE_COLOR_TEXT to #000000 for selected color. when you click on item text color will change to black.